# Adding all custom capabilities to admin

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

When adding a custom post type using the "capability_type" argument, custom capabilities are automatically generated for the post type.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#capability_type

Ie registering a post type named "cars"

```
'capability_type' => array('cars', 'car')
```

Automatically generates 'edit_cars', 'delete_car' etc.

Afterwards, these capabilities can be added to a custom user role to control their access and permissions. So far so good.

But.. Isn't the administrator role supposed to have all capabilities including custom ones per default?

When using the above approach, my admin users loses their permission to edit the post type in question.

What is the correct approach here? Should all custom caps be added to admin role manually like they are added to other roles?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct approach here? Should all custom caps be added to
> admin role manually like they are added to other roles?

Yes, because `register_post_type()` will not automatically assign the capabilities to any users or user roles, including administrators, but if Multisite is enabled, then those who are super admins would always be able to manage (e.g. edit or delete) the posts in the post type, unless if `do_not_allow` is present in their capabilities (as returned by [`map_meta_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/)) — see [`WP_User::has_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/has_cap/).